# Counting items in categories

Tags: beginner, haskell, functional-programming

I'm an experienced programmer that also has *a little* experience with functional programming, although mostly theoretical (as in hobby-level reading and very minor projects).

I recently decided to work through the new book "Beginning Haskell" to get up to speed with Haskell and try to crank out something worthy of a github repo. Early in the book you are asked to implement a `Client` ADT including some supportive data types for Person and Gender. I did it like this and I'm not liking it at all:

```
data Gender = Male | Female | Unknown | None
              deriving (Show, Eq)

data Person = Person { fName :: String, lName :: String, gender :: Gender }
              deriving (Show, Eq) 

data Client = GovOrg { code :: String,     name :: String }
            | Individual { code :: String, person :: Person }
            | Company { code :: String,    name :: String, contact :: Person }
              deriving (Show, Eq)
```

After this you are asked to write a function that takes `[Client]` and returns the count for the different genders, e.g. "out of the 20 clients listed, we have 5 male, 5 female, 10 unknown". Let's call it `countGenders`. Below is the code I've ended up with, and I feel that it's a complete mess and lacks any feeling of clarity or elegance. I think my OOP-brain is forcing me into bad designs. I'll walk you through the lines below. Once again I am not at all happy with this.

First we have a result data type. Could be just an `(Int, Int, Int)`, but I feel like the location in the tuple isnt a natural fit with what the data should represent (as opposed to `Point Int Int`):

`data GenderCount = GenderCount { male :: Int, female :: Int, unknown :: Int }`

Then we have the top level function that is supposed to be invoked. Maps `genderCount` across a `[Client]`, which results in `[(Int, Int, Int)]`, then unzips those and sums each list.

```
countGenders :: [Client] -> GenderCount
countGenders cs = GenderCount (sum m) (sum f) (sum u)
    where (m, f, u) = unzip3 $ map genderCount cs
```

Then we have genderCount, which maps a Client to a result tuple (Male, Female, Unknown):

```
genderCount :: Client -> (Int, Int, Int)
genderCount c = case cGender c of
                     Male    ->  (1, 0, 0)
                     Female  ->  (0, 1, 0)
                     Unknown ->  (0, 0, 1)
                     None    ->  (0, 0, 0)
```

Last we have cGender, which gets the gender from a client (using `RecordWildCards` extension):

```
cGender :: Client -> Gender
cGender GovOrg {}         = None 
cGender Individual { .. } = gender person
cGender Company { .. }    = gender contact
```

**As you can see this is all a mess.** But I'm having trouble thinking of how to refine it. I feel like my data model is bloated, which bleeds over into too many functions to do something that should be really simple. I would appreciate any feedback on the data model, the functions or anything else.

Here is the entire code if you want to look it over in full context: http://pastebin.com/Vymcd6Bj

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't that much of a mess at all. Let's clean it up, then get a little fancy.

Right off the bat it seems a little funky to have a `None` `Gender`, as it appears you're not actually trying to account for agender individuals but instead providing for the failure to produce a `Gender` for a particular `Client`. Operations that might fail in Haskell usually signal so by returning a `Maybe` value, so let's drop `None` from the definition and see what needs changing.

```
data Gender = Male | Female | Unknown
              deriving (Show, Eq)
```

`genderCount` and `cGender` depend on `None`, let's start with the latter. `c` doesn't mean much as a prefix to me, so I'm going to call this function `clientGender`, but that's a stylistic preference. Changing this function to use `Maybe` is straightforward.

```
clientGender :: Client -> Maybe Gender
clientGender GovOrg {}       = Nothing
clientGender Individual {..} = Just (gender person)
clientGender Company {..}    = Just (gender contact)
```

Now let's turn to `genderCount`. The first thing to notice is that the function is a tiny wrapped up `case` statement. This is usually a code smell to me that hints at a missed opportunity to break functions into smaller, more independent pieces. In this case `genderCount` has nothing to do with `Client`s, so let's rip that part out!

```
genderCount :: Gender -> (Int, Int, Int) -- Counting Genders, not Clients!
genderCount Male    = (1, 0, 0)
genderCount Female  = (0, 1, 0)
genderCount Unknown = (0, 0, 1)
```

This is still unsatisfactory, right? There's that convention-typed tuple, and we've got a perfectly good `GenderCount` datatype lying around, so let's use it.

```
genderCount :: Gender -> GenderCount
genderCount Male    = GenderCount 1 0 0
genderCount Female  = GenderCount 0 1 0
genderCount Unknown = GenderCount 0 0 1
```

It's a small change, but users of `GenderCount` can rely on the field names rather than a tuple ordering.

And now `countGenders`, the piece that glues it all together. Our type is still correct, which is awesome! No changes there. The implementation though is doing a few different things we'll need to adjust. In an informational sense it's determining the genders of all of the clients, then accumulating a count of each `Gender`. What it looks like though is some weird tuple math to produce a `GenderCount` value from nowhere! We can rewrite it given our new implementations to be a little prettier, but first we're going to need a way to add two `GenderCount`s together.

```
addGenderCounts :: GenderCount -> GenderCount -> GenderCount
addGenderCounts (GenderCount m f u) (GenderCount n g v) = GenderCount (m + n) (f + g) (u + v)
```

A lot of repeated instances of `GenderCount` in there, but that's not so bad given we can use this as a combinator. Now we can put our `countGenders` function together.

```
countGenders :: [Client] -> GenderCount
countGenders = foldr (addGenderCounts . genderCount) (GenderCount 0 0 0) . mapMaybe clientGender
```

This works! I've imported `mapMaybe` from `Data.Maybe` here to account for our `clientGender` function sometimes returning `Nothing` (`mapMaybe` drops all the `Nothing`s and returns a list of the `Just` values). We use a right fold to accumulate our `GenderCount` values, and a starting value of `GenderCount 0 0 0` for our accumulator.

There are a few ways to go from here to clean things up further. You could get rid of the `GenderCount 0 0 0` value by using `foldr1`, at the cost of adding another composition with `map` into the mix. If you have sharp eyes and a working knowledge of the [Typeclassopedia](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Typeclassopedia) you'll note a striking similarity between the way we use `GenderCount` with a right fold, and a `Monoid`. If you don't have a working knowledge of the Typeclassopedia, our motivation is that `Monoid`s allow us to specify an identity element and an associative reduction operation, revealing some higher level abstractions (and functions) we can use to wire our code together. Let's make a `Monoid`.

```
instance Monoid GenderCount where
    mempty = GenderCount 0 0 0
    mappend = addGenderCounts

-- Laws:
-- mempty <> x = x
-- x <> mempty = x
-- x <> (y <> z) = (x <> y) <> z
```

I won't prove the `Monoid` laws, but you should be able to see that they are trivial given the properties of addition and our definition of `GenderCount`.

Let's try one more pass at `countGenders` now.

```
countGenders :: [Client] -> GenderCount
countGenders = foldMap genderCount . mapMaybe clientGender
```

Nice!

Comment: Thanks a lot! You really got what I felt was at the heart of the issue for me - a misused data model. I had an inkling that `Maybe` would be better than a None gender, but it just bloated my code more. The `mapMaybe` function helps a bit with that and makes it a lot cleaner though.

I'm aware of the Monoid type/laws and could see its applicability to the problem but wasn't sure how to proceed.

Comment: Glad to help! I find the best way to learn about nifty little functions like `mapMaybe` is to read through the [docs for `base`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base). Anywhere in the `Data` or `Control` namespaces is probably a good place to start.